# How to test the Uber deep links API?

Tags: uber-api

we are developping an app which gives the user a list of travel proposals. The list will also include a travel proposal with Uber. 
To book a Uber travel, our app will start the Uber app over the deep links API. After booking the user will be able to jump back to our app with the trip branding feature.

How can we test this? Does Uber provide a test app? Or do we have to use the productive app for this?

Thank you for a reply.
Jean-Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test using the production app by generating a deep link from your app. See more details in the [deep linking documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction#ride-requests).

Comment: Also, at the moment, there is no way to test trip branding without requesting an Uber ride:  https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/trip-branding#override-defaults-within-setpickup-action

Comment: Thank you Dustin and Kyle for your replies, this confirm what I suspected. I have to book a real ride to test trip branding. I overlooked the note in the documentation.